# Using builder inside another builder in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is it a good practice to use builder inside another builder in Java or it would be better to add methods to builder of 'higher' level to create object behind the scenes?

```
new Car.CarBuilder().engine(new Engine.EngineBuilder().name("Diesel").weight(5).build()).build();
```

Comment: This way is good, because it means you don't have to duplicate things about the engine building in the `CarBuilder`, or add methods to `EngineBuilder` to "backtrack" back to `CarBuilder`. This way means, for example, that you can reuse `EngineBuilder` to build other types of vehicle.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean by the alternative?

Comment: Get rid of the `new` calls and make those into static `builder` methods. So that you can do `Car.builder().engine(Engine.builder()...build()).build()`

Comment: I would overload the `CarBuilder.engine` method with a `Supplier<Engine>` which makes it more flexible. The `EngineBuilder` logic can then be extracted to another method and a method reference can be used. Sadly the question is on hold, so I can't provide a full answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is ultimately a subjective question.

That said, as a counterpoint: Java code in Google's codebase uses a *lot* of builders, especially for data objects like protocol buffers. There is a general stylistic preference in favor of avoiding local variables if an inline expression suffices, which leads to a lot of code that looks like your example.

One notable difference is that Google style encourages a thing called the **rectangle rule** (which unfortunately I can't find a link for, although it's mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/6uvf9d/what_is_the_rectangle_rule_when_formatting_code/)). (I want to say that John DeTreville came up with the idea, but I'm not 100% certain.) In essence, the rectangle rule says that you want each expression within a statement to fit within a rectangular block of characters. Within an expression's rectangle there can be sub-expressions (each within their own rectangle), but no part of an outer expression should be within the inner expression's rectangle.

(When I was there, consensus was that a closing paren of an outer expression didn't count as invading an inner rectangle, but a closing bracket of an outer control statement did. Obviously you can spend all day debating style issues like this.)

This means that the preferred way of writing something like you show would look more like:

```
Car car =
    Car.builder()
        .engine(
            Engine.builder()
                .name("Diesel")
                .weight(5)
                .build()
        )
        .build();
```

or, more commonly (bending the rectangle rule a little):

```
Car car = Car.builder()
    .engine(
        Engine.builder()
            .name("Diesel")
            .weight(5)
            .build())
    .build();
```

I personally find that last example easiest to read: it's compact without being busy, and draws attention to the important parts of the statement without distracting the eye with unimportant details. And the general layout of the text matches the data structure, which also aids understanding.

Of course, this is just a stylistic choice. But the fact that a very large and successful codebase has made this choice indicates that it's not *wrong* to write code this way, and if you like to do that, you should feel free to go ahead.

Comment: Your examples are not what the RR gives. You need a newline + indent after the =.

Comment: I like this. I have subconsciously done this for a long time but not strictly.

Answer (score 3):

Reusing the builder logic in another build is fine as stated by  Andy Turner in its comment : you don't want to duplicate code.
But performing the chaining in this way is really not readable :

```
Car car = new Car.CarBuilder().engine(new Engine.EngineBuilder().name("Diesel").weight(5).build()).build();
```

You could format it differently but it still is not straight understandable :

```
Car car = 
new Car.CarBuilder().engine(new Engine.EngineBuilder().name("Diesel").weight(5).build())
                    .build();
```

Extracting the `Engine` instance in a local variable appears really much clearer :

```
Engine engine = new Engine.EngineBuilder().name("Diesel").weight(5).build();
Car car = new Car.CarBuilder().engine(engine).build();
```

Comment: I disagree: doing one method call per line, with the nested builder at a nested indentation level, seems the clearest for me. I think it's substantially easier to read than the two-variable version.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden I get what you mean. I think that it is taste question and I agree that a good formatting may help to understand better. What I like with the "two variables"  way is that exposes the two types side by side : `Engine engine =...; Car...=` You don't need to read the whole statement to understand the global idea.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this approach:
- build engine first
- then build the car using dedicated `engine(...)` setter

```
Engine engine = new EngineBuilder().name("Diesel").weight(5).build();
Car car = new CarBuilder().engine(engine).build();
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I will use this code to prepare some data set and therefore I'd like to write every car in single line to make it more readable